# What are the most important materials to mine at the beginning?

Tags: astroneer

Just landed on a planet, what should I be looking for in order to start building my base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very beginning, without being able to go too far, it's really important to find **Compound** so you can craft **Tethers** and go seeking for an interesting cave where you can get a lot of Resources. After you can move far away from home and have a "*tethers' net*", you should focus on finding **energy** and **resin**, being this one the most important as it's the material used for building **modules** and **links**, the basic structures of the game.

Whenever you get to this point, where you already have some usefull modules and energy generators such as solar panels or turbines, I'd suggest going for **copper** used for the **Printer** but this is just a *personal preference*.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 you need LOTS of.

## 1 - Resin.  Its required for base modules.  Without it you can't expand your base which means you can't make anything, can't research anything, and can't generate much energy.

## 2 - Compound. Its used in construction of the majority of the things you need early on such as tethers and medium storage panels.  And beacons.

Nice to haves...

## 3 - A few copper.  One load at least.  You will need it for some base modules.  Build a work light for your backpack also.  That makes seeing in caves and night easier.  And you need it for a drill head but thats much later.

## 5 - Aluminum.  Lots.  You need it for small and large wind vanes.  And you need it for the larger vehicles.  And you need it to make the vehicle module.

## 6 - Lithium.  Grab what you can early on.  One for a small battery, two for a medium battery.  The small battery in your pack extends your mining time.  The medium one on your base stores energy produced from wind and light for use when neither is producing.  Also used on rovers for extended range.

## 7 - Titanium.  Fairly low on the need list.  Used for the winch.  Little else that I know of.  Certainly nothing high level importance early on.